# Is there a name for this kind of power cable?

Tags: power, cable

I really like these PC power cables with the flat, side-by-side wire instead of the fat round ones you usually see.

[image]

I can't seem to find them on Mouser, etc when searching for "flat". Do they have a particular name?

**Edit:** not asking about the connectors but how to find the finished cables.

**Edit #2:** I actually need one with NEMA 5-15-P on one end and female C13 on the other (like a standard US PC power cable). I couldn't find a picture of one since they are so hard to find online! The "Mickey Mouse" style ones shown below seem pretty easy to find but not NEMA 5-15-P :(

Comment: "Flat Cable" obviously. Sorry this had to be said and can be deleted....

Comment: The common name is "Mickey Mouse" cable. Or you mean the cord itself and not the connectors?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I believe he's referring to the cord itself with each of the conductors lined up side-by-side. I don't think he's referring to either of the plugs. "Flat side-by-side cable instead of fat round ones"

Comment: @DerStrom8 Yeah, probably, so added the clarification question...

Comment: Is it CENELEC approved?

Comment: @winny - Agreed - it's not my specialist area, but I'm concerned about that too. I have a memory (from long ago, so not guaranteed to be correct) that the outer sheath, which is missing on that "flat cable", was a requirement for flexible mains cables to meet what was then BS6500 (later superseded & harmonised in Europe). So I wouldn't be surprised if selling such cables was illegal in at least some parts of the world...

Comment: These types of AC cords are discouraged because they are likely to result in a more dangerous situation, than round cords, when the flat-style cords are damaged.  I believe this is because it's easier to accidentally cut just one conductor, leaving equipment 'live', and you dead.  Check your local regulations.

Comment: Be aware that this type of cable is probably only rated for 120V, not 230V.  That's why cables sold in Europe and other 220 to 240V regions use round insulated and sheathed cable.

Comment: Are you looking for the type of *cordage* used to make such a power cable, or the name of the cable itself?

Comment: From the OP's edit "how to find the connectors" - those connectors are molded on the cable during manufacture - you won't be able to buy them to build your own cable.

Comment: Thanks all – sorry for any confusion, I'm trying to find the flat cables (I know which NEMA connections I need). Surprisingly, a search for "flat power cable" doesn't turn this up at all!

Comment: Re safety concerns: I'm using these in a very controlled (non-consumer) setting your comments are really helpful for anyone else who reads this!

Comment: @SimonB – is there any reason, beyond a single conductor getting damaged, that it wouldn't be safe for 220V? I've received them with consumer electronics rated for 120-240V.

Comment: @JeffThompson It's purely down to safety margin - and 230V will hurt a lot more than 120V.  European cables have two layers of insulation for extra safety.  I have seen US laptop cables used on 240V UK supplies.  Provided the cable is in good condition, nothing goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Mickey Mouse' end is an IEC 320-C5 connector, and the standard wall-prong end is NEMA 5-15P. Googling "IEC C5 flat cable" yields lots of results.

If you're looking solely for the flat cable without the connectors, google "flat power cable", "flat extension cord", etc. It's just a cable that's flat; to my knowledge there isn't a specific naming standard other than "flat cable".

Ribbon cables are flat also, but make sure they're rated for the current you're drawing.

Links to websites I found selling these:

https://leeselectronic.com/en/product/42141.html

https://www.sfcable.com/6ft-ultra-low-profile-nema-5-15p-to-c5-right-angle-power-cord-3-slot-18-3-awg-spt-2.html

[https://www.amazon.com/Dell-5-15P-Power-Adapter-Laptop/dp/B018Z9NU9U](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018Z9NU9U)

[https://www.amazon.com/Toshiba-Gateway-Notebook-Computer-Charger/dp/B01JBDY3GS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JBDY3GS)

Comment: Thanks @Darius, but I'm looking for a complete cable not the name of the connections. Those Google searches, at least for me, don't show the cables I'm looking for (mostly just right-angle plugs).

Comment: @JeffThompson check my edited answer.

Comment: – thanks! I edited my question to clarify what I didn't make clear before: for some reason the Mickey Mouse cables used in laptop chargers seem common, but I am looking for one with the more standard US PC power connectors.

Comment: @JeffThompson A flat cable w/ a C13 connector at a right angle may not exist. Here's one that's straight (Dell 5120P): https://www.amazon.com/PartsCollection-05120P-5120P-Power-Cable/dp/B01N5O5D1O

Comment: Nice find! Straight is totally fine. My hope now is for a more reliable search term so I can spec out options.